# Screen recording within android using libgdx or not

Tags: android, video, libgdx, recording

I managed to do  this by taking a series of screenshots and convert them to video using ffmpeg (ffmpeg compiled for android and include all *so to asserts, copy them all to  to data/data/my.package/ and execute ffmpeg from there)

But the main problem is the taking screenshots have big impact on screen rendering, it freezes a while (~0.1sec) when the app is executing this line of code:

```
Gdx.gl.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

I tried to take screenshots from another thread, but i only get black screenshots. Why???

Do you know a more efficient way of taking screenshots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screen capturing is a fairly expensive task, and more so when you want to turn it into a video.

The glReadPixels method is the method for reading back pixel values from the display buffer. Which is what you want; however, the limiting factor will be bandwidth to/from the GPU, especially for mobile devices. I would suggest creating a [FrameBuffer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.html) with a lower resolution (maybe half your width/height) so that you can reduce the bandwidth requirements. You would then draw your app to that buffer while it is active and then read back the pixel values. Libgdx provides a convenience class for reading back the pixel values in the [ScreenUtils](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ScreenUtils.html) class. (These methods use glReadPixels to do the reading).

Even then, it is likely to not work well on lower-end devices especially if you are thinking of recording video from the device at 60 frames a second AND actively rendering a complex scene. However, if someone else knows a way to efficiently do this on android devices I would be very interested in seeing a better solution.

To answer your other question, you can't access the OpenGL context concurrently and should be doing it only from the rendering thread. This is why you are getting black screenshots with multiple threads.

**Edit:**

To follow up with your question about how to export to a PNG I have code for that which you may use:

```
public boolean export(final FileHandle target, final Graphics g) {
        boolean error = false;
        final Pixmap picture = new Pixmap(g.getWidth(), g.getHeight(), Format.RGBA8888);
        final FrameBuffer buffer = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, g.getWidth(), g.getHeight(), false);
        try {
            Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glViewport(0, 0, g.getWidth(), g.getHeight());
            buffer.begin();
            g.render(); // Or however you normally draw it
            final byte[] data = this.readData(g.getWidth(), g.getHeight());
            buffer.end();
            picture.getPixels().put(data, 0, data.length);
            PixmapIO.writePNG(target, picture);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            error = true;
        } finally {
            picture.dispose();
            buffer.dispose();
        }
        return error;
    }

    // Adapted from ScreenUtil class
    public byte[] readData(final int width, final int height) {
        final int numBytes = width * height * 4;
        final ByteBuffer pixels = BufferUtils.newByteBuffer(numBytes);
        Gdx.gl.glPixelStorei(GL20.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL20.GL_RGBA, GL20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

        final byte[] lines = new byte[numBytes];
        final int numBytesPerLine = width * 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            pixels.position((height - i - 1) * numBytesPerLine);
            pixels.get(lines, i * numBytesPerLine, numBytesPerLine);
        }

        return lines;
    }
```

Comment: Agree with you. FrameBuffer with a lower resolution is faster. The main problem is how to save the FrameBuffer to PNG? Tried like this but unsuccessfull: m_fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, (int)(w * m_fboScaler), (int)(h * m_fboScaler), false);
              m_fboRegion = new TextureRegion(m_fbo.getColorBufferTexture());
              m_fboRegion.flip(false, true);
              m_fbo.begin();
     Texture lTx;
     TextureData lTxData;
     lTx = aTxRegion.getTexture();
     lTxData = lTx.getTextureData();
     pixmap = lTxData.consumePixmap();

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you an example of how to save to a PNG. You will likely need to adapt this code, but it should help.

Comment: I recently see the app Talking Tom has audio video recording feature of the screen at native resolution. How did they achieve that good framerate? Which framework did they use?

Comment: Gdx.gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL20.GL_RGBA, GL20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels); takes too long  even if i reduce the width and height. I need Screen Video Recording With Hardware Acceleration Support as IOS does.

Comment: Libgdx won't be able to help you there with the hardware acceleration for video recording. I would suspect the app would use FFmpeg to do the recording, but that is something outside of libgdx. It might be a good starting point for you to look at but I'm not familiar with that library.

Comment: do anyone know which recording engine use Talking Tom?

Comment: http://outfit7.com/eula-android/ go to section "20. Third party Technology" it lists them all.

Comment: they are using ffmpeg for conversion of screenshots to video. the main issue is how did they achieve such high level of frame rate

Comment: HEY I MANAGED TO RECORD AT 60fps :) check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Hello I managed to take a video @ 30fps or we can even get a video @60 fps from my idea and my video is super smooth

If anybody is intereseted please check this out.

The idea is simple we want screen shot of every frame with a 60fps or 29.97fps(my video).

Done in 3 steps:
1) render everything at 1/60 as delta time of screen

2) take screenhots of every frame

3) make a video of all those png files(i use adobe premiere pro)

Step 1) in libgdx i extend the Game class and make a new class MyGame extends Game
or class MyGame extends ApplicationListener
now change its render method for temporary use

```
ScreenShotUtils screenShotUtils=new ScreenShotUtils();
@Override
    public void render () {
        //if (screen != null) screen.render(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        //write your video fps as 1f/29.97f or 1f/30f
        if (screen != null){
            screen.render(1f/60f);
            screenShotUtils.update();
        }
    }
```

Step 2) capture screenshots using the capture method of ScreenShotUtils class
call the capture method when you need to capture just make a button in your game to start and stop recording

```
//call on start click
screenShotUtils.capture(true);
//call on stop click
screenShotUtils.capture(false);
```

Note: when you will start the capture the game will lag, it will be super slow, but the render delta time will not let the ui update less then 60 fps and you will get screenshots at 60 fps, now play the game during this lag and you will have smooth image sequence during video publishing

```
public class ScreenShotUtils {
    String filefolder="D:/capturefolder";// your folder to put the images in
    String filenameprefix="";
    int frameid=0,captureLimit=-1;
    private boolean isCapturing=false;
    public void setCaptureLimit(int frames){
        captureLimit=frames;
    }
    public boolean isCapturing(){
        return isCapturing;
    }

    public void capture(boolean capture){
        if(capture){
            if(!isCapturing) {
                isCapturing = true;
                filenameprefix="Demo"+System.currentTimeMillis();//Images Prefix
                frameid=0;
            }
        }else{
            isCapturing=false;
            captureLimit=-1;
            frameid=0;
        }
    }
    public void capture(boolean capture, int frames){
        if(capture){
            if(!isCapturing) {
                isCapturing = true;
                filenameprefix="Demo"+System.currentTimeMillis();//Images Prefix
                frameid=0;
            }
            captureLimit=frames;
        }else{
            isCapturing=false;
            captureLimit=-1;
            frameid=0;
        }
    }

    public void update() {

        // render before capturing

        if(isCapturing) {
            if(captureLimit<0)
                saveScreenshot();
            else
                if(captureLimit==0){
                    isCapturing = false;
                    captureLimit=-1;
                }else{
                    saveScreenshot();
                    captureLimit--;
                }
        }
    }
    private void saveScreenshot() {
        int MAX_DIGITS = 6;
        String fname = "" + (frameid++);
        int zeros = MAX_DIGITS - fname.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < zeros; i++) {
            fname = "0" + fname;
        }

        FileHandle file = new FileHandle(filefolder+"/"+filenameprefix +"-"+ fname+".png");
        Pixmap pixmap = getScreenshot(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);
        PixmapIO.writePNG(file, pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
    }
    private Pixmap getScreenshot(int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean flipY) {
        Gdx.gl.glPixelStorei(GL20.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(w, h, Pixmap.Format.RGB888);
        ByteBuffer pixels = pixmap.getPixels();
        Gdx.gl.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL20.GL_RGB, GL20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

        if (flipY) {
            final int numBytes = w * h * 3;
            byte[] lines = new byte[numBytes];
            final int numBytesPerLine = w * 3;
            for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
                pixels.position((h - i - 1) * numBytesPerLine);
                pixels.get(lines, i * numBytesPerLine, numBytesPerLine);
            }
            pixels.clear();
            pixels.put(lines);
        }     

        return pixmap;
    }
}
```

3) i used adobe premiere pro for video making, you can use other tools search google(convert image sequence to video)
https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/importing-still-images.html
Section: Import images as an image sequence

Note: i use screenshots of format RGB not RGBA because the alpha bits were messing with the borders of the images. you can try it

Aditionally you can modify the code to save files to android sdcard i used the desktop version, just change the saveScreenshot method's file handle

Disclaimer: i used the screnshot codes and modified them from this website http://www.wendytech.de/2012/07/opengl-screen-capture-in-real-time/

Comment: you can use ffmpeg and use the following command
"ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i input%06d.png -codec copy output.mp4"
change the %06d to your counter length
or change mp4 to mkv

Comment: You could use any sort of screen recording software to do this automatically on a computer. The point in the original question was to do this in real-time on an android phone.

Comment: @Jyro117 The code will work on android phone too, and will run smooth on high performance devices, but it will be ok on low performance devices too, plus the screen recording softwares decrease color quality and fps on my intel i5 pc and this method actually produces a smooth output and actual color on both android and desktop.