# Libgdx video and audio recorder

Tags: android, libgdx, record, android-mediacodec

I am a new guy in LibGDX base on some AR scene. I am trying to implement a video&audio recorder for LibGDX. I am researching the many materials only one StackOverflow poster solution about getting each frame Pixelmap maybe make sense ([Screen recording within android using libgdx or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729338/screen-recording-within-android-using-libgdx-or-not)) , base on my knowledge if I can build FrameBuffer via LibGDX probably I can via some other way use MediaCodec to create *.mp4 video file. But I really do not how to do it.
Right now I via MediaProjection to build the video record, but this solution is so ugly.
I also would like to know how to get LibGDX each frame textureId?
So I’m here to ask how to make the record for LibGDX.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screen recording within android using libgdx or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729338/screen-recording-within-android-using-libgdx-or-not)

Comment: No, in fact, this answer solution is ugly, each frame need to read Pixelmap the via offline to build mp4 this does not make sense for my project. I am still researching.